# Unexpected behaviour of useState (do not renew a constant after getting server data)

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple react code, which I use to track containers location on a territory. After a new container get's into the territory I have props.operationsList changed. So I send get response to server API when props.operationsList changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchContainerLocation() {
      const response = await CoordinatesService.getContainersPosition()
      console.log('response = ', response.data.features)
      setContainersList(response.data.features)
      console.log('containersList = ', containersList)
    }
    fetchContainerLocation()
  }, [props.operationsList])
```

I need to update containersList const, that I use to rerender a map API where I should locate the containers. I define it like that:

```
 const [containersList, setContainersList] = useState([])
```

I need to set containersList in accordance with that response fron server (response.data.features) to make my map rerender. What's strange,

> console.log('response = ', response.data.features)

shows accurate and correct data from server, but the next

> console.log('containersList = ', containersList)

is not equal with this response

[image]

Instad of getting the map rendered with the right data from server response, I have wrong data. So, I do now understand why such an straightforward approch do not work and how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

State updates in React are asynchronous; when an update is requested, there is no guarantee that the updates will be made immediately.

So, try to log your `containersList` outside useEffect and compare both logs. both should be same.

**TIP**: While using map method with your containerList use it like `containerList?.map()` so that page does not turn out to be blank.

```
const fetchContainerLocation = async () => {
  const response = await CoordinatesService.getContainersPosition();
  console.log("response = ", response.data.features);
  setContainersList(response.data.features);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchContainerLocation();
}, [props.operationsList]);

console.log(containerList);

return (
  <>
    {containerList?.map((container) => (
      <p>something you want to render</p>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Yes, but how to renew containerList correct way? I need it to be equal with the response data

Comment: `setContainersList(response.data.features)` is already renewing your containerList.

Comment: Yes, but could you provide some more details regarding you tip with map() ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I've made in like that `<ObjectManager features={containersList.map((container) => container)}` There's no changes :-(

Comment: I have used ternary operator `?` with containerList.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249267/discussion-between-drashti-kheni-and-ivan).

Comment: I wrote in chat

Answer (score 1):

No idea why, but it worked when I changed ***response.data.features***
to ***[...response.data.features]***

Working code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchContainerLocation() {
      setContainersList([])
      const response = await CoordinatesService.getContainersPosition()
      setContainersList([...response.data.features])
    }
    fetchContainerLocation()
  }, [props.operationsList])
```

If anybody could explain why, it would be useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).